# This program uses a ton of memory due to a huge vector, how can I prevent it from doing this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I was browsing r/dailyprogrammer, and I came across a challenge I thought I could figure out.

I'm not going to go into detail, but the gist of it is that there are plants that produce 1 fruit every week, with the amount of fruit they produce increasing by 1 every week. These produced fruits are planted to create more plants. The program runs until enough fruits are being produced so that 1 person gets at least 1 fruit in a population, the size of which is determined by the user.

The point here is the vector I'm using to hold the plants is causing a huge amount of lag and makes the program take ages to run. Here is the entire thing, annotated for easier comprehension:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void funnyPlant() {

    int startPlants, //initial plants (determined by user)
        people,      //population (determined by user)
        fruits = 0,  //fruits that the plants produce weekly
        week;        //integer representing time passed

    cout << "Enter population: ";
    cin >> people;
    cout << "Enter initial plant quanity: ";
    cin >> startPlants;
    vector<int> plant(startPlants); //vector is created with each element representing
                                    //1 plant, the value of which representing the amount
                                    //of fruit it produces in a given week

    cout << endl << "Processing, please wait..." << endl;

    for (week = 0; fruits < people; ++week) {
        fruits = 0; //fruits is reset because they are all planted immediately
        for (int i = 0; i < plant.size(); ++i) {

            fruits += plant[i]; //total fruits from each plant are tallied, to determine
                                //if there is enough for the given population

            ++plant[i]; //plant's fruit bearing capacity is increased by 1
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < fruits; ++i)
            plant.push_back(1); //each fruit is planted, increasing the size of the vector
    }

    cout << week << " weeks required for sustainability" << endl;
    cout << "( " << plant.size() << " plants producing " << fruits << " fruits)";
    cout << endl << endl;
}

int main() {

    funnyPlant(); //function is executed
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the problem lies with my use of a vector to represent the amount of plants.

```
plant.push_back(1);
```

A higher population demands more time, which causes the amount of fruit being produced to reach astronomical quantities, which in turn causes the vector to expand to massive sizes, taking up a huge amount of memory.

Is there any way around this, or can I simply not use a vector? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a map, and if the item is missing assume it has no fruit

Comment: Consolidating identical plants would probably cut down drastically on memory usage, and probably computation time as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of holding everything in vector you should count number of plants with production of *i*, so suppose you have vector `Cnt`, on the first step you have `Cnt[0] = startPlants`, on next steps you *"shift"*, which is copy `Cnt[i]` to `Cnt[i + 1]` in decreasing of *i* (which means that everything that produce i will produce i+1 on the next step). And for `Cnt[1]` you add sum of `Cnt[i]*i` before *"shift"*.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like to demonstrations of full solutions but I feel like I have to as most suggestions are far from optimal.

[Please note: There is no math environment so it will look a bit ugly.]

You have the following informations:

- At the beginning there are `p_0` plants. Those plants will produce one fruit each (in the first week).
- (There are no fruits at the beginning.)
- Every week all plants are harvested and the `f_w` harvested fruits will be planted as new plants. These plant will produce one fruit each (in their first week).
- All `p_w` already existing plants will increase fruit production by one fruit every weak.
- There are `P` people who need to be fed, meaning you want to have at least `P` plants planted.

In short terms this reads

```
startvalues: p_0, f_0=p_0
recursive relation: w -> w+1
    p_w+1 = p_w + f_w        // the following week every harvested fruit of this week will be planted
    f_w+1 = f_w + p_w+1      // the following week the production will increase according to the number of total plants after planting
          = f_w + p_w + f_w  // that is: every already existing plant will produce one more fruit and every new planted one will start producing one fruit
```

Given these relations one can easily implement an algorithm with just three variables (third es `w` which you probably want to know after reaching `f_w >= P`). This means: Only `O(1)` memory is needed! Runtime is `O(weeks)`. As the fruit production is increasing extremely fast - more than exponential - which means that it is not linear in the number of people this seems to be a good result (and seems to be the best you can get).

---

**Warning: Following is just a try. I did not find any better solution than the one above.**

Let us go further and try to find a solution with a even better runtime.
Have a look at the recursive relation again. You may notice it is a simple linear dependency which you can express via a matrix vector multiplication `v_n+1 = A * v_n`:

```
/ p_w+1 \     / p_w +   f_w \   / 1  1 \ / p_w \
\ f_w+1 /  =  \ p_w + 2*f_w / = \ 1  2 / \ f_w /
```

Now we can express the values of the total numbers of plants and fruit production in week `w` directly with only knowing `p_0` and `f_0`(`=p_0`):

```
/ p_w \     / 1  1 \^w / p_0 \
\ f_w /  =  \ 1  2 /   \ p_0 /
```

Remember: We want to know the minimal `w` where `f_w >= P`.

The problem is that this multiple matrix products are still `O(weeks)`. But luckily the matrix is diagonalizable. (-> [Wikipedia: Diagonalizable matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), `A = S*D*S^-1`, if lazy use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,1%7D,%7B1,2%7D%7D) to compute the diagonalization)
So the following equation holds:

```
/ 1  1 \     / (-1-sqrt(5))/2  (-1+sqrt(5))/2 \   / (3-sqrt(5))/2        0       \   / -1/sqrt(5)  (5-sqrt(5))/10 \
\ 1  2 /  =  \       1                1       /   \       0        (3+sqrt(5))/2 /   \  1/sqrt(5)  (5+sqrt(5))/10 /
```

Now we can rewrite rewrite `A^w` to `(S * D * S^-1)^w` which is the same as `S * D^w * S^-1`.

So we get:

```
/ p_w \                        / p_0 \
\ f_w /  =  S * D^w * S^-1  *  \ p_0 /
```

As we only want to check for `f_w` we only need the equation

```
f_w = (cge^w + dif^w + che^w + djf^w) * p_0
```

where the constants `c`, `g`, ... are matrix entries of the matrices `S`, `S^-1` and `D`:

```
      / a  b \          / e  0 \             / g  h \
S  =  \ c  d /  , D  =  \ 0  f /  , S^-1  =  \ i  j /
```

[Note: `f` is not `f_w` and `f^w` is not `f^w` either. Sorry for the double usage of the letter f.]

Now reorder `f_w` and use `c=d=1`:

```
f_w = c(g+h)p_0 * e^w + d(i+j)p_0 * f^w
    = (g+h)p_0 * e^w + (i+j)p_0 * f^w
```

As `f_w` shall be greater or equal to `P` (the number of people) we now search for the `w` that holds

```
        P = (g+h)p_0 * e^w + (i+j)p_0 * f^w
<=> P/p_0 = (g+h) * e^w + (i+j) * f^w
```

Our new problem is that `g+h != i+j`. But we can use a trick. Rewrite the equation to

```
P/p_0 = (g+h) * e * e^(w-1) + (i+j) * f * f^(w-1)
```

with the relations

```
(g+h) * e = - 1 / sqrt(5)
(i+j) * f =   1 / sqrt(5)
```

we get

```
P/p_0 *sqrt(5) = - e^(w-1) + f^(w-1)
```

Well... This I did not get any further. Easy solutions to this equation or the following (equivalent with some minor constraints) are appreciated - or a prove that the recursive solution proposed above is already optimal.

```
a = x + x^c [need to be solved for x. a and c are some known constants derived from the above ones.]
```